# Question from Spring 2012 AMATYC Student Mathematics League

Tags: contest-math

How would you go about solving a problem like this:

> Let a, b, and c be positive integers which satisfy $a^3+b^3+c^2=2012$.
>   Find $a+b+c.$

It doesn't appear that there's enough information to solve if, but test is multiple choice and the answer provided are:

```
A. 28      B. 30      C. 32      D. 34      E. 36
```

Comment: Should that be $c^3$?

Comment: Is it safe to assume calculators are not allowed for teh competition?

Comment: @Michael there are no positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 2012$.

Since $2012 = 2 * 2 * 503$ and $8 | (2n)^3$, $a, b, c$ have to be made up of $2$ evens and $1$ odd. Case checking with a calculator confirms that this does not hold for any $(a, b, c)$.

Comment: Also, without checking, the min over positive integers of $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 2012$ and $a+b+c = 28$ is $(9, 9, 10)$ which is greater than $2012$

Comment: I googled the [answer from the contest site](http://c.ymcdn.com/sites/www.amatyc.org/resource/resmgr/student_math_league/rd2_solutions_2011.2012.pdf):
"A little number crunching! The largest value $a$ can be is $12$., but no integer choices of $b$ and $c$ work with that. 
When $a=11$, $b=8$ and $c=13$ work. So $a+b+c=32$".

Comment: [Rules](http://www.amatyc.org/?page=SMLRules)
"CALCULATORS: 
Students are permitted to use any scientific or graphics calculator 
that does not have a QWERTY (i.e. typewriter) keyboard."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a paper and pencil method to solve the problem without a calculator.

Let $n$ be one of the numbers from $\{28,30,32,34,36\}$. We know that 
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=2012-c^2 \tag{1}$$ 
and that 
$$a+b=n-c \tag{2}$$

From this follows that $a$ and $b$ are solutions of

$$3x^2-3(n-c)x+(n-c)^2-\frac{2012-c^2}{n-c}=0 \tag{3}$$

A necessary condition that an integer solution for $(3)$ exists is
$$n-c \mid 2012-c^2 \tag{4}$$.

We can assume 
$$n-c \gt 8 \tag{5}$$
otherwise
$$a^3+b^3+c^2 \le (a+b)^3+c^2 \le (n-c)^3+n^2 \le 8^3 + 36^2 <2012$$

$n-c$ is a divisor of $2012-c^2$ and therefore a divisor of 
$$f(n)=\frac{n}{(2012,n)}(2012-c^2)-(\frac{2012}{(2012,n)}+\frac{n}{(2012,n)}c)(n-c)$$

$(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

If  define $s(m,k)$ 
as the largest divisor of $m$ that does not contain a prime factor larger than $k$.
We have
$$d \mid m \; \text{and} \; d \le k \implies  d \mid s(m,k) \tag{6}$$

So we get 
$$n-c \mid s(f(n),n) \tag{7}$$
The table lists the values of $f(n)$ and $s(f(n),n)$

$$
\tag{8}
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n&f(n)&s(f(n),n) \\
\hline{} \\
28 & 307 \cdot c & c\\
30 & 2^2 139 \cdot c & 2^2 c\\
32 & 13 \cdot 19 \cdot c & 13 \cdot 19 \cdot c\\
34 & 2^2 107 \cdot c & 2^2 c\\
36 & 179 \cdot c &  c
\end{array}
$$

For $n \in \{28,36\}$ we get from $(4)$, $(6)$ and $(8)$
$$n-c \mid s((2012-c^2)+c \cdot c,n)$$
But $s(2012,n)=4$ and $(5)$ shows, there is no solution for $n=28$ and $n=36$.

For $n \in \{30,34\}$ we get from $(4)$, $(6)$ and $(8)$ 
$$n-c \mid s(4 \cdot (2012-c^2)+c \cdot (4c),n)$$
$s(4 \cdot 2012,n)=16$ and $(5)$ shows, the only possible value is $n-c=16$. 
But $16 \nmid c$, neither for $n=30, c=14$ nor for $n=34, c=20$.
So there is no solution for $n \in \{30,34\}$.

$n=32$:
We get $32-c \mid 13 \cdot 19 \cdot c$. Here we have three cases:

1. $32-c \mid c$
2. $32-c \mid 13$
3. $32-c \mid 19$

Case 1 gives no solution for the same reasons as for $n=28$ and $n=36$.

Case 2 gives $32-c=13$ or $32-c=26$.  therefore $c=13$. Substituting this values in $(1)$ gives the equations
$$  x^2-13x+14=0$$
and
$$x^2-26x+200=0$$
None of them has integer solutions.

Finally for case 3 we get $32-c=19$ and the equation

$$x^2-19x+88=0$$

with the two solutions $8$ and $11$.

So the solution to the problem is

$$8^3+11^3+13^2=2012$$
$$8+11+13=32$$

Comment: @Caminek: I have made a new revision that is much simpler and complete and removes a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd proceed by guessing. I know that $8^3=512$, so that's a good place to start. Then we'd have $b^3+c^2=1500$. Then I'm going to guess $b=11$, so we have $b^3=1331$. This yields $c^2=169$, which fortunately has a solution of $c=13$. This makes the answer 32.

There may be a better way to do this, but the very limited number of solutions to $a,b$ makes guessing reasonably easy.

Comment: I bute-forced the same with MATLAB, constraining
$a,b \in [1,12]$ since $12^3 < 2012 < 13^3$ and $c \in [1, 34]$ from choice $E$ ^^

Answer (score 0):

Although calculators I assume are not allowed, this is still quite easily guessed from trial and error. My advice to you would first work with large (a, b) and see if the resulting c will satisfy the equation.

The correct answer is 32 (8, 11, 13)